# C# and External Process Thread Behavor

Tags: c#, multithreading, casperjs

I have a Windows Service wrapping Quartz.NET that runs multiple long-running routines in parallel. Some of these routines launch CasperJS externally to scrape HTML. I have a situation where it *appears* that every so often, the results from one CasperJS scrape get consumed by the wrong thread. I realized that I have no idea *how* the process would know which thread it "belongs" to, so I'm assuming this could happen. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
Process casperProcess = new Process();
casperProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessOutputHandler);
casperProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorOutputHandler);
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(casperBatchPath + " ", runParms.ToString());
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
casperProcess.StartInfo = info;
casperProcess.Start();
casperProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
casperProcess.WaitForExit();
casperProcess.Close();
casperProcess.Dispose();
```

Comment: So in ProcessOutputHandler are you writing data into a static member. If you are you could end up with one thread changing the container before its written giving you the cross contamination your describing.

Comment: @muglio Yes, I meant to update this question today: that was exactly the problem. Realized it shortly after I posted, but forgot to update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer shortly after posting: the class had a static member, so naturally the threads were writing over each other. D'oh!